# Laravel - Use conditions when selecting data using controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following controller where **I try to select all the customers of a user** (The ones with `'user_id'` equal to the `'id'` of the **authenticated user**). I know how to do it in the following way, but as you can see it is not very efficient since **it selects more records than necessary**.

```
public function index() // Http/Controllers/CustomerController.php:17
{
    $user_id = Auth::id(); // Get user ID

    $customers = Customer::all()->where('user_id', $user_id); // Select all users and then filter by ID

    return $this->showAll($customers, 200); // Return JSON response with response code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `$customers = Customer::all()->where('user_id', $user_id);` to:

```
$customers = Customer::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-models

Comment: Perfect, I forgot the get() when I tried it, I will accpt the answer when I can. Thanks